# Webpage CSS Suddenly Displaying Wrong on Certain Pages

Tags: html, css, templates

I have a template applied to multiple pages on my website, including the About section. This section has three pages and the layout is the same for each page. The template isn't working correctly on two pages, about2.html and about1.html. Oddly, it works perfectly for about3.html

Previously these two pages worked fine on all browsers I viewed it on, and only recently did I notice it stopped displaying correctly, even though I didn't touch the template or CSS.

Here's one of the pages:
http://thehummingbirdplace.com/about2.html

I've tried rearranging different elements, disabling certain CSS, and deleting sections all together but it doesn't fix the page. When I delete the whole .adRight section or disable the float on it, the text moves back to the the top, but the menu tabs don't line up right. I honestly am not sure what's at the root of the problem, so I can't provide specific code here to focus on.

Comment: Try clearing your browsers cache or viewing it in another browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `css` inside `about1.html` and `about2.html` should look like this

```
<style style="text/css">
img { padding-top: 0px; padding-right: 15px; padding-bottom: 15px; padding-left: 0px; }
#text { width: 850px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
.img-left { flaot:left; }
.img-right { flaot:right; }
</style>
```

Next, you may clear these `divs` having class `clear` on both files - you don't need them, or at least change your `.clear` class to this, `.clear { clear: both; }`

```
<div id="header"><!-- ... --></div>
<div id="adLeft"><!-- ... --></div>
<div class="clear"></div>               <!-- take this off -->
<div id="adRight"><!-- ... --></div>
<div class="clear"></div>               <!-- take this off -->
<div id="content1"><!-- ... --></div>
<div id="footerLine1"></div>
<div id="footer"><!-- ... --></div>
```

Change the only img element inside the text block in `about1.html` to this

```
<img src="_images/Donna4.png" width="197" height="193" alt="Donna Wright" class="img-left" />
```

Change the only img element inside the text block in `about2.html` to this

```
<img src="_images/hummingbirdLogo.png" width="208" height="145" alt="The Hummingbird Place Logo" class="img-right;">
```